# Can I know if a bitcoin private/public key or address was derived from another key in an HD wallet by its structure?

Tags: address, private-key, bip32-hd-wallets, public-key, base58

If I have a bitcoin private key, public key or address, can I know if it is a root private key or some other part which derived from a root private key in an HD wallet by the structure of it?

To be more specific - I don't need to know any details about the parent keys or to connect a hierarchy between two keys - just to know by the structure if to treat this key/address as "unique" one in my program.

Comment: No, and that's a feature of HD wallets - you can't tell how keys or addresses relate to each other without knowing secret material. It's a privacy feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Individual address private keys [begin with 5,L or K](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key#Base58_Wallet_Import_format). What you're calling root private keys are actually called extended private keys and they begin with ?prv where ? is either x,z,y,Y,Z. You can see examples of those [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0032#Test_vector_1). So that's how you tell the difference.